# How can a force has nonzero value of its component perpendicular to it?

Tags: vectors

After scratching my head for more than 8 hours on to this I post this question on StackExchange. Here's the problem. Lets say I have a force vector $\overrightarrow{F}$. Now I can have its component at let's say $45^\circ$ which would be equal to $F\space cos(45^\circ) = F \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Now we have a component of $\overrightarrow{F}$ and lets say it $\overrightarrow{F'}$. Now again, take a component of $\overrightarrow{F'}$ in the same rotation at $45^\circ$ and lets say it $\overrightarrow{F''}$. So $$|\overrightarrow{F''}| = |\overrightarrow{F'}| \space cos(45^\circ) = \biggl(F \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\biggr)\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = F \times \frac{1}{2}$$ Now we can clearly notice here that $\overrightarrow{F''}$ is component of a component of main force $\overrightarrow{F}$ which is at $90 ^\circ$ from the main force and still has a nonzero value so indirectly a component of the main force has nonzero value. How is this possible?

[image]

Comment: 1. How is this a physics rather than a [math.SE] question? 2. Note that you can write any vector $v$ also as $v + w - w$ for arbitrary $w$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind 1. It is physics question because it is from Physics class 2. I have not understood this, please help

Comment: You've shown that the magnitude of vector F'' is related to the magnitude of vector F, but have you truly shown that vector F'' is a component of vector F?

Comment: @ACuriousMind If you replace force with electric field and mention polarisers, it would be a physics question. There are physical phenomena somewhat relevant to this question.

Comment: @electronpusher So if this is proved that value of $\overrightarrow{F''}$ depends on $\overrightarrow{F}$ and also it is nonzero then how can a nonzero force come out of nowhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can see $F'$ as a "component" of $F$. And the other "component" would be the mirrored image of $F'$ wrt the direction of $F$, let $F'^\dagger$.

Now when you further decompose $F''$ in a "component" along $F$ and one perpendicular to it, don't forget to decompose $F'^\dagger$ is a similar "component" along $F$ and $F''^\dagger=-F''$.

Comment: Thanks, this resolve my issue